# How to use getResources.getString(R.string) in an Interface?

Tags: java, android

I have an interface that has a static key. And I wanted to retrieve this key from a string file, but if I just put R.string.key, it shows incompatible types, because it retrieves the integer value, and if I put R.string.key + "", it becomes a string but retrieves the String file id, it would be best to use getResources.getString (R.string.key), but there is no way to use the getResources.getString method in the Interface.

Working:

```
public interface NotificacaoService {
    @Headers({"34853485734",
            "Content-Type:application/json"}) @POST("send")
    Call<NotificacaoDados> salvarNotificacao(@Body NotificacaoDados notificacaoDados);
}
```

I want to leave it like this:

```
public interface NotificacaoService {
    @Headers({getResources.getString(R.string.key),
            "Content-Type:application/json"}) @POST("send")
    Call<NotificacaoDados> salvarNotificacao(@Body NotificacaoDados notificacaoDados);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, what you want is not possible. Annotation parameters need to be constants.

One solution is to switch from string resources to `BuildConfig`. Use `buildConfigField` in your Gradle script to define your key (`buildConfigField "String", "API_KEY", "\"34853485734\""). Then, you can reference that generated constant in your interface (e.g.,`BuildConfig.API_KEY`).

Alternatively — if this interface is for Retrofit — you could add your headers via an OkHttp interceptor, instead of via a `@Headers` annotation.

Comment: I was able to use the Gradle file as you said, thanks